# Passing Python *list of arguments to object works inside of one method but not another?

Tags: python, django, list, arguments, args

I am trying to pass a list of arguments to a Django crispy form Tab() class.
First i build some buttons from the btn_list input and try to pass it back to the helper object.
I was able to make this work in the first example where I return the entire Tab() object. but am a bit confused as to why I cant return just the Div() objects as a list and then pass them as arguments into the Tab() object within the helper its self? seems when I use the asterisk in the helper python gives a syntax error.
Any ideas?

```
def build_button_list(btn_list):#generates a list of buttons from the given input
    base_fmt = 'btn btn-block '
    btn_layout = []
    for btn in btn_list:
        btn_layout.append(  Div( HTML("<b>"+btn['title']+"</b>"), \
                            Div(
                                Button('BtnProfile1', 'Persional Information', onclick="location.href='"+btn['link']+"'",
                                    css_class=base_fmt+btn['size']+" "+btn['style']),
                                css_class="row",
                                )
                            )
                         )

    return Tab('tab name', *btn_layout) #NOTICE THE ASTERISK * !!!! 

class gettingStarted(forms.Form):
    ....
    ....
    btn_list = [blah,blah]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
             TabHolder(
                  build_button_list( btn_list ), #makes a list of formatted buttons
             )
        )
```

However when I try change the layout and add the Tab object in the gettingStarted().**init**() method instead of the make_button_list() method, python complains of a syntax error and wont accept use of the asterisk:

```
def build_button_list(btn_list):
    base_fmt = 'btn btn-block '
    btn_layout = []
    for btn in btn_list:
        btn_layout.append(  Div( HTML("<b>"+btn['title']+"</b>"), \
                            Div(
                                Button('BtnProfile1', 'Persional Information', onclick="location.href='"+btn['link']+"'",
                                    css_class=base_fmt+btn['size']+" "+btn['style']),
                                css_class="row",
                                )
                            )
                         )
    return btn_layout

class gettingStarted(forms.Form):
    ....
    ....
    btn_list = [blah,blah]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                   # SYNTAX ERROR???
                   Tab(
                       'tab name', 
                       *build_button_list( btn_list ), #NOTICE THE ASTERISK *
                      ),
        )
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out when passing *args you can not have a trailing comma. I didnt notice it and kept wondering why when I added an asterisk python would complain and wouldnt complain when I removed it. thus the reason I assued it was the poor little asterisk's fault when infact it was that sneaky comma I left in there, which makes sense given the nature of what the asterisk actually does :)

so just to clarify this now works as expected:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
               Tab(
                   'tab name', 
                   *build_button_list( btn_list ) #NOTICE THE COMMA IS GONE!
                  ),
    )
```

Comment: For those who are interested, there's a [python-dev discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-December/106770.html) of this issue.